# Amount of Shake on Android phone. I want to detect Amount of shake using Javascript ( As I am using Phonegap)

Tags: android, jquery, iphone, cordova

I want to grade shaking. eg. Slow shaking Medium Shaking , Fast Shaking.  This is to trigger 3 different events.

I want to do this using Javascript as I am using Phonegap.

Is it possible to know frequency of Shake?

Thanks

VP

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of PhoneGap tells you exactly how to access the Accelerometer:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html

Using the code snippets provided on this website, you can define different offsets that qualify as slow, medium and fast shaking. Tweak the numbers by playing around with the demo code and your device to get a feeling what acceleration of the different x,y and z axis you feel is adequate for your purpose.